# Writing cos(π+i) in Cartesian form?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a problem writing cos(π+i) in Cartesian form (x + yi). I understand that it is usually written in the form cos(θ) + i sin(θ), but I don't understand how to obtain the sin part (and how to even write this in any other form e.g polar form).
any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Kuba just a math problem I have to solve, "Write the following complex numbers in Cartesian form".

Comment: Use the formulas and explanation here: http://www.milefoot.com/math/complex/functionsofi.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos(i+\pi)=-\cos(i)=-\cosh(1)$

Comment: Thank you, I guess there's no way around hyperbolic functions with this one (although by syllabus does not mention these anywhere).

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(\pi+i)=\frac{e^{i(\pi+i)}+e^{-i(\pi+i)}}{2}=\frac{e^{i\pi-1}+e^{1-i\pi}}{2}=\frac{-\frac{1}{e}-e}{2}=-\frac{1+e^2}{2e}\approx-1.5430806348...$$

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(\pi+i)
&=\frac{e^{i(\pi+i)}+e^{-i(\pi+i)}}{2}\\
&=\frac{e^{i\pi}e^{-1}+e^{-i\pi}e^1}{2}\\
&=-\frac{e^{1}+e^{-1}}{2}\\
&=-\cosh(1)
\end{align}
$$

Alternatively,

$$
\begin{align}
\cos(\pi+i)
&=\cos(\pi) \cos(i)-\sin(\pi)\sin(i)\\
&=-\cos(i)\\
&=-\cosh(1)
\end{align}
$$